# How to get the decrypt data from other user using GunDB

Tags: gun, gundb

I gave a try to `.secret()` and `.trust()` of gun.user though, there are unexpected results. How could I get the data from other users in order to **access control** in the application?
as well as I need to know **how to decrypt data** without the error message, 'Could not decrypt'.

- node 10.16.0
- gun 0.2019.515
- chrome 74.0.3729.169

There are User03 and User01 in left and right.
My goal of this test is User01 to get User03's secret data.

#### 1. Put data under the User03 and check the data on both consoles.

```
S.user.get('test').put('come on'); // on left console as user03

S.user.get('test').once(console.log); // on left console as user03
user03.get('test').once(console.log); // on right console as user01
```

[image: put and check]

#### 2. Let User03 `.trust()` User01 on left side.

```
S.user.get('test').trust( user01 ); // left
```

[image: trust]

#### 3. Make User03's data `secret` using User03's pair.

```
S.user.get('test').secret( S.user.pair ); //left
```

[image: secret]

#### 4. Check the encrypt data on both sides.

```
S.user.get('test').once(console.log); // on left console as user03
user03.get('test').once(console.log); // on right console as user01
```

[image: check secret]

#### 5. Decrypt user03's secret using user01's pair on the right.

it gets the error message, 'Could not decrypt'.

```
user03.get('test').once((data)=>{
    SEA.decrypt(data, S.user.pair, console.log);
});; // right
```

[image]

#### 6. Check the inside the return object of STEP 5.

[image]

I expect the output 'come on' as decrypted data.

Answer (score 1):

@huhsame , sorry for the delay on answering this. (For urgent matters, please tag me on Twitter or in the Gitter)

The main issue is that `User.trust` and `User.secret` are currently (August 2019) unstable alpha API methods.

We however have a stable production-ready lower-level API you can use instead, called [SEA](https://gun.eco/docs/SEA).

Here is a complete example of how to do what you want:

```
var alice = await SEA.pair();
var bob = await SEA.pair();
var enc = await SEA.encrypt('shared data', await SEA.secret(bob.epub, alice));
await SEA.decrypt(enc, await SEA.secret(alice.epub, bob));
```

This is what GUN and the User API methods use underneath.

You see that `alice` and `bob` are the same keypairs (pub & priv of ECDSA & ECDH) behind the `gun.user(ecdsaPubKey)` lookups you've probably already done.

`await SEA.secret(ecdhPubKey, alice)` gets a common shared secret between your target user's public key (their ECDH pubkey, not ECDSA) and "yourself" (Alice). How this is done is famously described with [mixing colors](https://youtu.be/YEBfamv-_do).

Then `.encrypt(` and `.decrypt(` do what you'd expect, as long as the have the same "passcode" (the 2nd parameter), which is gotten by deriving the common `secret` of two users, which gives the same output even in the reverse direction (Bob, the target user, passing his keypair as "you", and Alice's ECDH pubkey as 1st parameter into `secret`).

Hopefully this will buy you time, doing it yourself, until the `User.trust` and `User.secret` (in contrast to `SEA.secret` which works already) higher-level convenience methods are ready.